# How do I fix "application is not open anymore"

Tags: macos

I'm getting an error or the form "application is not open anymore"  when I try to start an application from the launchpad.

I cannot find the application in *Activity Monitor*. What is the cause of this, and how could I fix it. Ideally without restarting.

## References

- https://www.chriswrites.com/fix-macos-application-not-open-anymore-error/ This suggests killing in activity monitor and restarting
- https://osxdaily.com/2016/12/04/fix-application-not-open-anymore-mac-error/ Again suggests killing in activity monitor or restarting
- https://www.tenorshare.com/mac-os/fix-the-application-is-not-open-anymore.html This suggest killing in activity monitor or restarting. But also suggests deleting the applications information folder if this doesn't work
- https://appuals.com/fix-mac-the-application-is-not-open-anymore/ Again, suggests killing in activity monitor or restarting. Also suggests restarting in sage mode.

[image]

Comment: I know you are looking for a solution without restarting, but why? Is it a reocurring error or has this happened just once. If its the latter I would try restarting and see if the error comes back.

Comment: To clarify, is the vendor of duet app this - https://www.duetdisplay.com/ ?

Comment: @X_841 there error is reoccuring, but I have not tried restarting yet. I'm waiting to see if someone has the answer / some diagnostics to do this. The annoying thing about restaritng is that I have half a dozen applications open in a particular state that I'm using for work... as I always do when I'm working!

Comment: @bmike Yes, I'm trying to start `duetdisplay`

Comment: I totally understand the point about having apps opened in a certain state. However, the time you put into asking this question and now potentially looking for other clues could be much more than simply restarting and putting the apps back in the same state. I am not suggesting that you have no good argument, I am just saying that it *may* be more efficient (if a restart actually does resolve the error) to go that route.

Comment: `X_841` I quite agree. I guess in my head there are a few other things going on. I want to understand, I'm aware that it might happen again, I have slow builds running today and hate multitasking, putting it hear might get duet to look at it, and the fact that "paper cuts" have additional costs in terms of productivity and emotional impact.